# How to avoid casting?

Tags: java, android

I add new global hight level interface:

```
    public interface MvpView {
    }
```

My hight level interface:

```
public interface OfferDetailsView extends MvpView {

   public void showProgress();
}
```

Another interface:

```
public interface OfferDetailsPdfMvp {

    interface View extends OfferDetailsView  {

        public void openLocalPdfFile(File file, int pageNumber);

    }

    interface Presenter extends OfferDetailsPresenter {

        public void onPageScrolled(int page, int pageCount);

    }
}
```

Another interface:

```
public interface OfferDetailsPresenter extends MvpPresenter {

    public void downloadToAppDir(boolean isDownloadToAppCacheDir);

    public void onClickScreen(boolean isVisibleTopContainer);
}
```

Another interface:

```
public interface MvpPresenter<V extends MvpView> {
    public void attachView(V mvpView);
}
```

Base abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseOfferDetailsPresenter<T extends MvpView> implements MvpPresenter<T> {
    private T view;

     @Override
    public void attachView(T mvpView) {
        this.view = mvpView;
    }

   public T getView() {
         return view;
    }
}
```

And conrete class that extend from Base class:

```
public class OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImpl extends BaseOfferDetailsPresenter<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View> implements OfferDetailsPdfMvp.Presenter {    

    public void viewIsReady() {
      getView().showProgress(); //no cast
      getView().openLocalPdfFile(file, currentPageNumber); // no cast
    }
```

But I get compile error:

```
myproject\app\src\main\java\com\myproject\android\customer\presenter\OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImpl.java:35: error: MvpPresenter cannot be inherited with different arguments: <> and <com.myproject.android.customer.mvp.OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View>
    public class OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImpl extends BaseOfferDetailsPresenter<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View> implements OfferDetailsPdfMvp.Presenter {
```

Comment: [generics?](https://ideone.com/cw7p5E)

Comment: I also think about Generics. But I'm a new in Generics. Has any good examples?

Comment: It is hard to say what is going on - the *new* code isn't a [mcve]! I don't see a definition for `getView()` any more for example.

Comment: I update my post. Add `getView();`

Comment: Please add sources for `OfferDetailsPresenter`.

Comment: I update my post again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make what you want, you should change your `OfferDetailsPresenter` signature:

```
public interface OfferDetailsPresenter<T extends MvpView> extends MvpPresenter<T> {

    void downloadToAppDir(boolean isDownloadToAppCacheDir);

    void onClickScreen(boolean isVisibleTopContainer);
}
```

Then, inside `OfferDetailsPdfMvp` you should change `Presenter` signature in the same manner:

```
public interface OfferDetailsPdfMvp {

    interface View extends OfferDetailsView  {

        public void openLocalPdfFile(File file, int pageNumber);

    }

    interface Presenter<T extends MvpView> extends OfferDetailsPresenter<T> {

        public void onPageScrolled(int page, int pageCount);

    }
}
```

And then populate desired `View` as you do with the `BaseOfferDetailsPresenter<T extends MvpView>`:

```
OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImpl extends BaseOfferDetailsPresenter<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View> implements OfferDetailsPdfMvp.Presenter<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View>
```

Comment: I get another error: `\myproject\app\src\main\java\com\myproject\android\customer\presenter\OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImpl.java:36: error: type Presenter does not take parameters
 

 public class OfferDetailsPdfPresenterImpl extends BaseOfferDetailsPresenter<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View> implements OfferDetailsPdfMvp.Presenter<OfferDetailsPdfMvp.View> {`

Answer (score 1):

You can't - with that signature.

Keep in mind, `getView()` says:

```
OfferDetailsView getView()
```

Thus: the signature of this method uses one of your base interfaces.

There are only two choices:

- change the return type to a more specific sub interface / class
- do an instanceof check + cast

Just *assuming* that `getView()` returns some specific class and having an unchecked cast is *not* good practice. On other hand: when it is clear that `getView()` will return an instance of `OfferDetailsPdfMvp` then it shouldn't be a big deal to change the method signature accordingly.